# Java 8 loop arraylist of object and add element if condition verified

Tags: java

I am trying to use java 8 stream. I checked the other posts and I do not understand why my code below is causing an error. Someone can tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you

```
private OptList myFunction(OptList childOpts, Opt subOpt) {
        OptList results = new OptList();
        for (Opt o : childOpts) {
            if ((subOpt.getOptPri() == null || subOpt.getOptPrices().isZeroPrice())
                    && (o.getOptPrices() == null || o.getOptPrices().isZeroPrice())) 
            {
                results.add(o);
            } else 
            if (subOpt.getOptPrices() != null && o.getOptPrices() != null) {
                if (subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.MS).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.MS))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.DISC).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.DISC))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV_DISC).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV_DISC))) 
                {
                    results.add(o);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    private OptionList myFunction(OptList childOpts,
                                            Opt subOpt) {
        return childOpts.stream()
                .filter(o -> (((subOpt.getOptPrices() == null || subOpt.getOptPrices().isZeroPrice()) && (o.getOptPrices() == null || o.getOptPrices().isZeroPrice()))
                        || ( (subOpt.getOptPrices() != null && o.getOptPrices() != null) && (subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.MS).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.MS))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.DISC).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.DISC))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV))
                        && subOpt.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV_DISC).equals(o.getOptPrices().getPrice(PriceType.INV_DISC)))     )))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: The error is : collect (java.util.stream.Collector<? super net.cds.data.model.Ioption,A,R>) in Stream cannot be applied to (java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>, java.util.List<T>>). Should I cast the returned list by doing something like .collect(OptList(Collectors.toList())) ??

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have two functions, one implemented using regular collection operations, and the other implemented using streams, and you want to know why the second doesn't work.

I don't know what `OptList` is, but it's not going to be a `List<Opt>`, which is what `collect(Collectors.toList())` is going to return. You need some way to make the `collect` function return `OptList`.

You have two options.

If `OptList` is a (extends) `Collection<Opt>`, then you can use `toCollection` and pass an a function that produces an OptList:

```
childOpts.stream(). (other stuff) .collect(Collectors.toCollection(OptList::new))
```

This works because the `collect` method knows how to call the `add` method of the resulting `Collection`.

If `OptList` is not a collection type, then you can still use `collect`, but you have to [build your own collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-). You will need to supply a function that creates the output type, a function to add a new member to it, and a function to combine two of the output types into one, which will be used if you are collecting parallel streams.

It will probably look something like this:

```
childOpts.stream(). (other stuff) .collect(OptList::new, OptList::add, OptList::addAll)
```

If `OptList` doesn't have an `addAll`, then you can try passing `null` (not sure if that will work!) or passing a function that throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Thank you very much Willis BlackBurn. OptionList extends ArrayList<Option> and doing this .collect(Collectors.toCollection(OptionList::new));  has solved my issue. Thank you so much

Comment: Great--could you accept the answer (click the check button next to it)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using your own **List** implementation. 
**Collectors.toList()** does return a standard collection type: `List<Opt>`.

Therefore your first option is to use the standard like

```
private List<yourType> myFunction(OptList childOpts, Opt subOpt)
```

or if `OptionList` implements `List`, then you are able to change your collect call to:

```
Collectors.toCollection(OptionList::new)
```

This little example provides some info on the returned types and standardtypes:

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
System.out.println( 
   values.stream().collect(toList())
    .getClass().getTypeName() );
System.out.println( 
   values.stream().collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new))
    .getClass().getTypeName() );
```

It prints:

```
java.util.ArrayList
java.util.LinkedList
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the `myFunction` method :

```
private OptionList myFunction(OptList childOpts, Opt subOpt) {
    return childOpts.stream()
            .filter(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It takes a list of `Opt`s (`OptList`), eliminates those who don't match a certain criteria, then groups them back with the `toList()` collector, which returns a `java.util.List` of the items that are streamed.

So the expression's return type (and thus the whole method's return type) should be `List<Opt>` or a supertype of it (eg. `Collection<Opt>`).

Your current method signature is therefore wrong, and the compiler complains.